# How can I create my own app package?

Tags: command-line, bash, package-management, scripts, flatpak

I will give an example:
There is .deb, .appimage, flatpak, snap, AUR, etc, but I want to create my own (Example app.fictionalpackage)

Maybe zipping a folder with files inside and renaming ".zip" to ".WhateverIWant", making a reader for that zip in bash script, which reads the contents of the zip without extracting, and from that content, it reads a file- mother inside the zip that basically has the directories where its files should be extracted, along with specifications on how the .desktop file should be created?

I thought of something like that. Any idea?
In fact, I have no knowledge of anything outside of shell scripting, and within it I still know little.

I'm pretending to create the more lightweight, basic package type and the installator client of it, on the world.

It would be cool if was sandboxed too, like flatpak or snap, and had a control panel to manage its permitions.

Any idea? *(Whorever, if anyone want to make it, you can copy my idea)*

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Congratulations! You have just re-invented the deb package, originally invented in 1993-1994. Very early debs did indeed use the zip format before changing to ar.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Source: https://xkcd.com/927/

> Maybe zipping a folder with files inside and renaming ".zip" to ".WhateverIWant", making a reader for that zip in bash script, which reads the contents of the zip without extracting, and from that content

That's how .deb packages work, except that the files are compressed in an `.ar` archive.

> I'm pretending to create the more lightweight, basic package type and the installator client of it, on the world.

While snap and flatpak are not very lightweight, existing distribution formats like .deb packages are indeed very lightweight.
Other distros have their own existing (lightweight) native packaging format as well.

We really need more (and better) apps in GNU/Linux. The existing packaging formats are good enough. If you have an idea for a useful app, please share the idea / create the app and share its GitHub repository (on websites like https://discourse.ubuntu.com/).

Comment: Thank you, my friend! Also, I didn't knew that deb packages act like this.
We need a ".deb" for arch-linux. There is something like that to arch?

Comment: Arch packages come in a compressed `.tar.zst` format. You can install them with `sudo pacman -U /path/to/package.tar.zst`, just like you install `sudo apt install /path/to/package.deb` in Ubuntu. In case you want to download a package in the official repositories, open the relevant page of the package (e.g. https://archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/foliate/) and click on the `Download from Mirror` link on the webpage. However, almost everything that is not in the official repositories in Arch is available on the AUR, this is almost never necessary.

Comment: Thank you, @Archisman Paniagrahi. The problem of AUR is that, some packages break, and ocasionally your entire system break too. This is the great problem of Linux: A simple "apt-get" or "pacman" can break your entire system. Timeshift is a hero on that situations, but it takes so much storage from the system.

I would like some universal "flatpak" format that can install everything, like AUR, tar.zst, deb, and every this inside a container and without needing to install again the dependencies. Maybe a adicional package just to store de dependences of the another packages would be cool.

Comment: @Felipecconde I always install regular packages and AUR packages separately in Arch, and don't use AUR for critical system packages (e.g. kernel, desktop interface, etc.). Also, from my experience, Manjaro (which stockpiles updates) breaks a lot more than Arch or EndeavourOS (which release updates as soon as they are available). I have been using Arch and EndeavourOS in two computers for almost one year, and did not have any issue so far. Sometimes, I had to manually intervene during the installation of an AUR package, and that's it.

Comment: Interesting. Hm, just a question. What do you mean by "installing AUR and regular packages separately"? You have two different installation paths for it? I did not understood. How do you do this?

Comment: I update AUR packages with `yay --aur` and regular packages with `sudo pacman -Syu`.